Confused about using "the" in mathematical English writing
I am not an English native speaker. In many times, I have seen different authors used "the" or not used "the" in the same situation. I am so confused about this. Here are some examples. The first example,

... operations on the ideals of $R$ ...
... operations on ideals of $R$ ...

The second example,

... the definition of the xxx operation ...
... the definition of xxx operation ...

The third example,

... all the ideals of $R$ ...
... all ideals of $R$ ...

Could anyone tell me which one in the above is right or give some other explanations?

This is a linguistic question, not a mathematical one. The word "the" has multiple meanings and usages: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/definite-article

Both are correct, though I couldn't explain why or whether there's any slight semantic difference. For that, you might want to ask on the Linguistics or English Language stack exchange.

Mathematics uses lots of words and constructions idiosyncratically, as part of math jargon, (that's jargon in the sense of "specific to a field", not with the sense of "slang"), so I think this is a valid question to ask mathematicians. But sadly I think you'll just get opinions, which will put this outside of the permitted questions range.

As far as the math is concerned, I believe the examples you mentioned are the same. But you must be careful about the distinctions between "the" and "a/an" in contexts of definitions, and uniqueness. For example, "the ideal of $R$" carries the implication that $R$ is a ring with exactly one ideal, whereas while referring to "an ideal of $R$", no such property of $R$ is implied.

(+1) for the "the" and "a/an" distinction you make. I've explained it this way to prospective ESL writers of mathematics questions for certain high-stakes graduate program admissions tests: Use “the” when making reference to a unique object, such as a specific object previously mentioned. Use “a/an” when making reference to one of possibly several objects. Interestingly, this distinction is almost always ignored, even by native English speakers, (continued)

when referring to a proof, such as: "The proof of this assertion is given below, but first we mention $\ldots$" (instead of "Our proof $\ldots$" or "A proof $\ldots$")

@DaveL.Renfro Why not active rather than passive voice? "We prove this assertion below, but first ...". It's less wordy and bypasses "The" vs "A" vs "Our" proof.

Could you tell me which one in the following I should use at the beginning of a sentence? "The ideals of $R$ are one the the following forms..." or "Ideals of $R$ are one of the following forms...". Should I always add "the" like "the ideals of $R$" to ensure it sounds correct? It is hard for me to tell the differences.

@user1082245 IMHO, "Ideals of $R$ are ..." could be understood as ""Some ideals of $R$ are ..."

Ethan Bolker: Why not active rather than passive voice? --- Because I didn't realize I was doing it!
